# Removing camera button on iPhone lock screen

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, screen-lock

How to remove the camera button on the iPhone lock screen without removing the camera from the springboard

I don't want to allow people without access to take pictures using my phone (pictures are shared automatically by iCloud)
But in the same time, I want to be able to use the camera from the springboard.

I'm searching for a **native** solution under iOS 8.x or later

Comment: You might get better answers if you indicate whether solutions requiring a jailbreak would be ok for you.

Comment: I'm searching for a native solution only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way this can be done is by using Settings > General > Restrictions to disable the use of the camera completely. A side effect is that FaceTime is also disabled.

There is no other mechanism built-in to do what you want.

Comment: another side effect is that all your applications using the camera don't work anymore

Comment: Complain at the Genius Bar?

Answer (score 2):

There is no native solution for what you want. But to answer your problem of automatically sharing pictures to icloud, you can disable the feature of sharing automatically.

```
Settings -> icloud -> photos -> turn off photo sharing
```

This may not be a complete solution, but can reduce the risk of sharing everything. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can just disable access to any functions from the lock screen by going to "Settings" > "Control Center" and then turn off access from lock screen.

Comment: This only controls the presence or absence of the Control Center on the lock screen, and does not answer the OPs question.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry, but the answer is no. There is no native solution to this. You can always turn off the camera settings though

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer... but with less detail

Answer (score -4):

There is no native solution for what you want. But to answer your problem of automatically sharing pictures to icloud, you can disable the feature of sharing automatically.

Comment: 1) this answer already exists and 2) please don't spam us